# Cannot verify Line bot Webhook

Tags: heroku, bots, webhooks, line-api

I tried to make LINE bot based on this site:
https://www.casleyconsulting.co.jp/blog/engineer/3028/

I got an error  when I push verify button.

```
The webhook returned an HTTP status code other than 200.(503 Service Unavailable)

Confirm that your bot server returns status code 200 in response to the HTTP POST request sent from the LINE Platform. For more information, see Response in the Messaging API Reference.
```

I αm not sure how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what link did you put on the Line Developers website? You might have forgotten the `/callback` at the end...

Else, have you tried to send a message without verifying?

And the last question: did you write that command?

```
heroku git:remote -a {HEROKU_APP_NAME}
```

If you didn't try it before your `git add .` command.